# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes or freezes after login (dual boot, nvidia graphics)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia, crash, nvidia-geforce

I have a dual boot system (Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10) and most the time it works fine, but occasionally at startup, after selecting Ubuntu from GRUB Boot and logging in) the system will crash and I'm presented with the following output

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, XXX/XXX files, XXX/XXX blocks
[195.544151] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
[195.544179] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM Init failed (-110)
```

Or:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clearning orphaned inode XXX (uid=XXX, gid=XXX, mode=XXX, size=XXX
...
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, XXX/XXX files, XXX/XXX blocks
```

Sometimes the system just freezes and I'm unable to do anything at all.

Windows was installed first, then Ubuntu afterwards. I did have to modify the kernel parameters to be able to actually use the Ubuntu installer:

```
quiet splash nomodeset reboot=warm,acpi
```

After Ubuntu finished installing I also downloaded / updated the Additional Drivers to use NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-435(proprietary, tested)

Specs / Equipment:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Dual Booted (Windows 10 Pro N)
- AMD Ryzen 3700x
- 8-core processor * 16
- GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2
- 64-bit
- Logitech G915 Wireless Keyboard
- Logitech G703 Wireless Mouse
- Corsair HS70 Wireless Headset

*Note: Windows works fine, no issues*

**Edit:**

It appears to happen when too many applications open too quickly after logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While restarting, press Escape to enter Grub menu.
Press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit Ubuntu option, after quiet splash text, add `pci=nommconf`.
Then, press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save & boot.
After logging in install Grub Customizer.
In the app Go to **General** then **Kernel Parameters** and add `pci=nommconf` after `quiet splash`.

I also have an Omen 15 Laptop with GTX 1050, i7, 12 GB Ram, this fixed it for me, and the Nvidia drivers.

If it persists, Upgrade to a newer kernel, or switch to 20.04 LTS ( Which I HATE. ) But if it doesn't, I would try upgrading kernel, as it will support newer GPU's.