# Ubuntu doesn't start after dual boot set-up

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I have a Asus Zephyrus G14,
(Ryzen 5 4600HS, GTX 1650 4GB GDDR6 Graphics, Gaming Laptop 8GB RAM/512GB SSD/Windows 10) that has Windows 10 pre-installed.

I tried to set-up Ubuntu 20.04.01 by following couple of guides (https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ and https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/ )

Here are the things that I have done.

1. Disabled secure boot in BIOS
2. USB flash drive as 1st boot location in BIOS (for installation)
3. During installation start I appended this at the end of the line that starts with linux. "nouveau.modeset=0" (However I see a 3 dash at the end of the line so I just added the "nouveau.modeset=0" before the 3 dashes.. screenshot attached)
4. Completed the installation.
5. After the installation is complete, Ubuntu asks for restart. But instead of restarting, I closed the dialog, opened the "Update Manager" (as described here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/#verification), I saw nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested). Installed and then shut down the computer.

Removed the USB drive and start the laptop.

I do see boot option for Ubuntu and Windows.
However when I select ubuntu, I see a black screen with a cursor blinking.

I feel I must be missing something basic. I have added few screenshots for reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am still able to boot into Windows though.

Can any one help provide some pointers please?

** Update 1**
I followed the instructions here: [Ubtunu 18.04 crashes or freezes after login (Dual boot, nvidia graphics)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231804/ubtunu-18-04-crashes-or-freezes-after-login-dual-boot-nvidia-graphics)
But that didn't improve anything for me. Same black screen with a blinking cursor at the top left hand corner.

**Update 2**
I followed the answer under section "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time" in askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/67529 , going the nomodeset route helped me resolve the problem. Here are the steps I followed.

Following this answer [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
I was able to boot the Ubuntu atleast once in i.e. used nomodeset option from boot screen
I removed the "quite splash" and added "nomodeset"
Press F10 and went to software updater to install "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested)".
Restarted the laptop and it worked fine after that.

*Big thanks to the Ubuntu community.*

Thanks,
Ayusman

Comment: Be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mnode. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  If nVidia correctly installed, you should stop using nomodeset.

Comment: Same laptop, same problem with Linux Mint 20.2. Testing Ubuntu 21 next.